# Convert an array of 2 name/value objects keys to a single name/value

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

When using jQuery's `serializeArray()` on my form I get an array that looks like this:

```
[{
  "name": "name",
  "value": "1_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "1_caption"
}, {
  "name": "name",
  "value": "2_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "2_caption"
}, {
  "name": "name",
  "value": "3_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "3_caption"
}, {
  "name": "name",
  "value": "4_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "4_caption"
}]
```

But the rest of my code expects something more like this:

```
[{
  "name": "1_filename.jpg",
  "caption": "1_caption"
}, {
  "name": "2_filename.jpg",
  "caption": "2_caption"
}, {
  "name": "3_filename.jpg",
  "caption": "3_caption"
}, {
  "name": "4_filename.jpg",
  "caption": "4_caption"
}]
```

I'm new to manipulating arrays and objects like this and I'm not sure if there is already a convention that's used to convert the first to something similar to the second example.

My first guess is to just iterate by 2 and push them to a new object. I've tried iterating by one and checking the names but I'm having some trouble making sure the name and captions stay together correctly.

Comment: How looks like the raw data before you call the `serializeArray()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single loop which iterates over every other element of the array:

```
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
    output.push({ name: input[i].value, caption: input[i + 1].value });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vejkmny2/)

This is obviously rigidly tied to the assumption that the order of objects will be nameN, captionN, nameN+1, captionN+1...

If this assumption is not correct, you would need to implement your own `sort()` logic to put the input data in to the right format before creating your new array.

Comment: Thanks for this! In the end I found this version easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Loop by two, build an object, set the name and value into the obj for the two indexes, and push object into the array

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "name",
  "value": "1_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "1_caption"
}, {
  "name": "name",
  "value": "2_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "2_caption"
}, {
  "name": "name",
  "value": "3_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "3_caption"
}, {
  "name": "name",
  "value": "4_filename.jpg"
}, {
  "name": "caption",
  "value": "4_caption"
}];

var out = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2){
   var obj = {};
   obj[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
   obj[arr[i+1].name] = arr[i+1].value;
   out.push(obj);
}
console.log(out);
```